# Open, save and close Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

I have an issue opening a spreadsheet via PowerShell, renaming a worksheet, saving and closing Excel. The issue is when run the first time the `$WorkBook` variable is null. If I run it a second time the script works fine. Also if I add `$ExcelDoc.Visible = $true` the script works fine. Does anyone have an idea why the script fails on it first run in the form it is below?

```cs
$Path = "C:\ScriptRepository\CQC\DataToLoad\"
$FileName  = (Get-ChildItem $Path).FullName
$FileName2 = (Get-ChildItem $Path).Name

Start-Sleep 2

$ExcelDoc = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$WorkBook  = $ExcelDoc.Workbooks.Open($FileName)
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.Worksheets.Item(2)
$WorkSheet.Name = "CQCProviders"

$WorkBook.Save()
$WorkBook.Close()

$ExcelDoc.Quit()
While([System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ExcelDoc)) {}
```

Comment: I don't know much about PowerShell, but what about a small pause/wait after instanciation of Excel app, to allow it to complete properly ? The fact that the script works fine when Excel is made visible makes me bet on that.

Comment: Good call, I have however tried it with a 20 second Start-Sleep with the same result unfortunately

Comment: Is there a typo in your $Path definition (ending with a "\")? If there are multiple files in that directory, $FileName will be an array of files and I doubt that Excel's Open method can cope with that.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your time, there is only ever 1 file in the directory at all times, it does create $FileName correctly even if it fails. As mentioned it will run the second time around ruling out typos.